# pCloud Your download expired. Try previous step again

Tags: php, api, cloud, pcloud

i use pcloud infrastructure for users' uploading files on our website.

however i am having problems with the api. In the download function in file.php

```
$ fileLink = $ this-> getLink ($ fileId);
```

we are using.but after a while to users say "Your download expired. Try previous step again." Gives a fault. I wonder if there is a way to solve this?I want unlimited download time.Thank you for your help

API Github: http://github.com/pCloud/pcloud-sdk-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer.

you must add this code on download function, before return line;

```
        header('Content-Description: Description');
        header('Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
        fclose($file);
        fclose($source);
        readfile($path);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. How you figure this out, as its not mentioned in api. Also does 'Expires: 0' is key, and can we also use it for java script based api call?